# Pshat in Pasuk of Velo Yavor

Tags: calendar, midrash, megillat-esther, tractate-megillah

Chazal say that the reason why we don't read the Megillah on the 16 is because the passuk ([Esther 9:27](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00793.html#HtmpReportNum0008_L2)) says "velo yavor" - וְלֹא יַעֲבוֹר.

Why is there a need for this Passuk? The Megillah said that the reading may only take place on the 11 till the 15.

Why then would I need a verse to tell me "not the 16"?

Comment: Maybe the five days are 14 through 18?

Comment: @Double AA. The Gemorah makes it clear that there's sources for 11 through 15. See 2a.

Comment: IIRC there are sources for 14 15 and three other days. Where are those three days though?

Comment: Those are merumaz. Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: @David - you assert that "The Megillah said that the reading may only take place on the 11 till the 15". It doesn't! I've read it over 100 times and even written it twice. Please start by sourcing that (at which point the question probably answers itself, I suspect.)

Answer (score 1):

The verses don't sat that the reading takes place between the 11th and the 15th. Rather this is derived in the Gemara (Megillah 2b) from various phrases in the Megillah including the words "vlo yaavor"

Incidentally, even had the Megillah listed the days, v'lo yaavor could still be valuable for teaching us an actual prohibition of performin kriyas hamegillah at other times (See Mordechai to beginning of Megillah)